# How to make cin take only numbers

Tags: c++

Here is the code

```
double enter_number()
{
  double number;
  while(1)
  {

        cin>>number;
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input " << endl;
        }
        else
        break;
        cout<<"Try again"<<endl;
  }
  return number;
}
```

My problem is that when I enter something like 1x, then 1 is taken as input without noticing the character that is left out for another run.
Is there any way how to make it work with any real number e.g. 1.8?

Comment: Read everything into a string and parse the input accordingly?

Comment: Use cin.get() and then check for EOF character?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use `std::getline` and `std::string` to read the whole line and then only break out of the loop when you can convert the entire line to a double.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    double d;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> d)
        {
            if (ss.eof())
            {   // Success
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Finally: " << d << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    
   int n;

    while (!(cin >> n)) {

        cin.clear();

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << "Invalid input! Please try again with valid input: ";
    }
   return n;
}
```

Comment: i think this may help u understand easily

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).