# how to loop back if a user enters a letter instead of a number c++

Tags: c++

My program identifies that a user has entered a letter instead of a number, but it doesn't ask for user input after that. I need to be able to prompt the user to enter another value that is a number and create a loop or something that will check the value every time to make sure it isn't a letter/s.

This is the part of my code that does the check for invalid character:

```
while (!cin.good())
{
cout << "Error! I only accept numbers! Enter in a number." << endl;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make cin to take only numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-to-take-only-numbers)

Comment: That forum question doesn't work for me. It doesn't prompt the user to enter in the value again.

Comment: That is easily fixed by changing `std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;` to whatever you want.

Comment: Your `while` loop doesn't give the user a chance to enter anything.

Comment: @Mofayew _"that forum question ..."_ You should notice, that Stack Overflow isn't a forum.

Comment: when I put cin >> kWh in the while loop it doesn't prompt the user to re-enter. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: How do I loop back to have the user enter a number if they have entered a letter?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this may be... this answered my question: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/186890-c-excluding-letters-on-user-input/

Answer (score -1):

Just don't do this:

```
int j;
cin >> j;
```

Because what will only read numbers and you need to read things other than numbers so you can report an error when they are entered.

Comment: I have to create a variable for kWh. so my variable can't be j it is kWh.

Comment: @Mofayew It's not the name of the variable that's the issue, it's the way you're reading.

Comment: Please help me better understand then. I am doing "double kWh; cin  >> kWh;"

Comment: Just don't do what I did in my second line. Don't try to read integers from `cin` because you need to read things other than integers so that you can report errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I don't use your second line you are saying don't ask for user input?

Comment: No, I'm saying "don't try to read integers from cin because you need to read things other than integers so that you can report errors". Ask for user input, but then have code that can read all the kinds of user input you need to accept, which includes things other than integers because you need to read them to determine that they're not integers.

Comment: To put it another way, you're thinking "only integers are valid for my program, so I'll use code that can only read integers". But that's not true. At the low level of the input routine, integers, characters, and all kinds of other things are valid input, they just cause your program to produce error output at the next level up. So you need input code that can read anything, analyze it, and decide whether to produce an error output or not. So that requires input code that can read more than just integers. So no `cin >> someInteger;`.