# Just input a number in cpp

Tags: c++

I'm need to create id just number. For example: 12345678
If user inputs fail( contain char), delete char immediately.
For example: 123a  =>input gain!
Please help me!

Comment: pleas share some code that you have tried and improve the question.

Comment: Maybe this answer:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829091/2785528 (check the others) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main () {
  std::string input;
  bool valid;
  do {
    valid = true;
    std::cin >> input;
    for (char c : input)
      if (! std::isdigit( static_cast<unsigned char>(c) ) )
        valid = false;
  } while (! valid);
  // Here the string is guaranteed to be valid
}
```

Be aware though, that whatever you are trying to do, this **does not** look like the proper way to do it. There are ways to read numbers in c++, and this is not what I would recommend.

Comment: You should cast the argument of `std::isdigit` to `unsigned char`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit.

Comment: char c : input ??? Please explain.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You're right, sorry I missed that

Comment: This is a range-based for loop. See [C++ Reference: Range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). This will iterate over the characters of the string input

Comment: @Sevis: Your edit made it worse. You still do not cast the argument to `unsigned char`, which would be necessary to prevent UB, but the *result*, which is wrong. Even worse, it's a C-style cast. The whole line should go like this instead: `if (!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)))`