# Should I use Exception handling for just invalid input?

Tags: c++, exception, inputstream

I've this example:

```
int main() {

    int val{};
    bool stop = false;
    char c;

    while (!stop) {
        std::cout << "val: ";
        try {
            if (!(std::cin >> val)) {               
                throw std::runtime_error("bad input");
            }
            std::cout << val << " : " << val * val << std::endl;
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "retry\?\n>>" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> c;
            if (c != 'y' && c != 'Y')
                stop = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The code works fine but I want to know should I use this in a real world program? Because I've seen some alternatives: getting the input as a string then using conversion to integral types.

- My question: is Should I use exception handling for invalid input like characters where it should be integers.. or Just sue string and conversion?

Comment: IMHO, there is nothing exceptional about bad input so exceptions should not be used.

Comment: There's nothing exceptional here, and a non-exception implementation would actually be shorter and clearer.

Comment: Well, it's a design choice, and in those cases, the answer depends on several factors in the real context. Anyway, why do you expect failure from `!std::cin`?

Comment: @BiagioFesta `std::cin` evaluates to true if the stream is in a good state.  So `!std::cin` will be true when the stream is in a bad state

Comment: Exceptions are very overused, and in cases such as this are mostly a goto that makes you feel good for not writing "goto". You can rewrite that as a straightforward `if-else`.

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah I know it, I am just curious to know why to expect failure in `std::cin`. I said so because I don't think it is a good way to implement a *"input parser validator"* if that what it meant to be here

Comment: @Biagio It's not (directly) expecting failure on `std::cin`, it's expecting failure on the `>>` operation

Comment: FWIW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829091/4342498) is how I would handle checking for bad numeric input.

Comment: Thank you guys! But what if the error in input stream is other than invalid input like a system-level error? Doesn't this also need E.H?

Comment: If you are writing serious input code (which you are probably not doing if you are using operator >>) then you should be looking at the individual stream status bits, such as `badbit` and in that case you might throw an exception, but it would be caught at the highest level of your code. Catching exceptions immediately after they are thrown is almost always wrong.

Comment: Alright, it the choice of the design. To me personally, I like to use the exception handling approach. In real-world programming, you might have tons of code and exception handling will benefit you. You can use this approach to throw your meaning full exception as necessary and centralize the logic in one place to handle those exception to communicate the message clearly to the user. In practical you might need to create your custom exception as well. For example ObjectNotFoundException, IllegalStateException, BadRequestException, ....

Comment: @NathanOliver So you mean in a real program I can use this: `while(!(std::cin >> x)){ std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');} std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;`?

Comment: @Maestro Yes.  Although that approach can potentially leave garbage in the buffer.  If you input `5a` for instance then `while(!std::cin >> x)` will store the `5` in `x`, `cin` will be good so the condition will be false and the loop wont execute.  That leaves `a` in the buffer and it will dirty the next input operation.  If you use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-take-only-numbers/10829091#10829091) that can't happen.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Snipped of your code showing the try/throw/catch in question:*

```
    try {
        if (!(std::cin >> val)) {               
            throw std::runtime_error("bad input");
        }
        std::cout << val << " : " << val * val << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
```

For the provided example, you would not use a try/throw/catch in *real world code*. Usually, you would prefer the simplest code to read and understand and for this case it is much simpler to avoid exception handling alltogether and use if/else instead:

```
      if ((std::cin >> val)) {                  
        std::cout << val << " : " << val * val << std::endl;
      }
      else {
```