# How to get the correct data type when the wrong data type is received

Tags: c++, types, infinite-loop, typeid

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (1) {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        if (typeid(num).name() != "int") {
            cout << "please input integer" << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

When I wrote the code like this, I thought that if the wrong data type was input, the `while` statement would be executed again by `continue`, and the variable `num` would be input again.

However, an infinite loop occurs instead. I would be grateful if you could help me with why.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-take-only-numbers

Comment: `while(1)` is causing the infinite loop. The `continue` statement has no effect. Maybe you want `else break;`?

Comment: If continue is used, does the while statement go back to the condition of the while statement?
Then, even if an infinite loop occurs, the value of num must be continuously received, but when executing the code, the sentence "please input integer" is repeated infinitely without receiving input.

Comment: @bongbong that is because `typeid(num).name() != "int"` is always true. You are misusing `typeid()` for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking whether `cin >> num;` succeeds or fails. And if it does fail, you are not `clear()`'ing the error before continuing.

You can't use `typeid()` to check for success/failure of `>>`.  That is not what it is meant for. `typeid(num)` is evaluated at compile-time, producing a  `std::type_info` that describes `int` itself.  An `int` will always be an `int`, regardless of what is assigned to `num` at runtime.  Besides, in your example, `typeid(num).name() != "int"` will always evaluate as true, since you are comparing a `const char*` pointer from `name()` to a string literal that is clearly stored elsewhere in memory, so the two memory addresses don't evaluate as equal.  And since you are doing that comparison inside a `while(1)` loop, that is why `"please input integer"` is printed out endlessly.  You don't have any viable error handling in your loop.

You have to look at `cin`'s actual state to know whether `>>` fails, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (1) {
        int num;
        // cin >> num;
        // if (cin.fail()) {
        if (!(cin >> num)) {
            cout << "please input integer" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limit<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }
        // use num as needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and it helped me a lot. Can I ask one more question?
cin.clear () says that it clears the error flag, but what does it do to clear the error flag and why is it necessary?

Comment: Read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear). If you don't call `cin.clear()` to reset `cin`'s error state then subsequent reads from `cin` (including the call to `cin.ignore()`) will fail immediately without even trying to read any data. When an error occurs in an `istream` (or `ostream`), the error persists until you manually clear it.